# Bluetooth not working in12.04 (Dell Inspiron 15R)

Tags: 12.04, dell, bluetooth

I am trying to get my Bluetooth working on Ubuntu 12.04 for my Dell Inspiron 15R Laptop.

I have tried installing Blueman, but yet Ubuntu is unable to access my Bluetooth Device. 
Could anyone help me with installing the drivers and configuring the bluetooth.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen much Bluetooth receivers lacking Linux support. However, there are other things to check here, I think.

- First of all, check that your wireless devices are unlocked (no rfkill active).

  ```
  sudo rfkill list
  ```

  In case bluetooth is 'Soft blocked' you can unblock it:

  ```
  sudo rfkill unblock all
  ```

  In case bluetooth is 'Hard blocked', try to find a hardware switch on your laptop to unblock it.
- Then, check your kernel messages for Bluetooth related stuff:

  ```
  dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
  ```
- And does your Bluetooth driver expose an hci device?

  ```
  hcitool dev
  ```

  should list for example `hci0`.
- Check your system BIOS that Bluetooth is enabled.
- Is your Ubuntu kernel up to date (and did you reboot after that)?
- Try installing the `linux-firmware` and `linux-firmware-nonfree` packages. Your device may require loading some proprietary firmware.

Comment: couldn't solve the issue with this information.As i googled further i came up with the information of editing the existing driver for the broadcom which was working with the previous release of ububtu,but ufortunately that also isn't working as expected.

Comment: @prajul I would suggest to ask your own hardware-specific question.

Comment: @gertvdijk +1 for answer

Answer (score 3):

Installing [linux-firmware-nonfree [image: Install linux-firmware-nonfree]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-firmware-nonfree) solved it for me, on a generic Bluetooth 2.0 USB adapter from Amazon.com. In my experience with Dell internal adapters, you have to blacklist any driver other than your specific one.