# Laptop bluetooth not working

Tags: 13.04, bluetooth

I have an MSI CR41 laptop, which has a bluetooth 4.0, before I was using Windows, but just recently I decided to totally leave Windows and switch to the open source and I chose Ubuntu as my new OS. Almost all of my hardware are properly working aside from my bluetooth, I couldn't find any bluetooth devices nor get discovered by another device. I am sure that my laptop and other bluetooth devices are in discoverable mode. I had done a lot of tweaks with the help of forums and this website. I have already installed the Blueman and also see (via the Ubuntu Software Center) that all of the other stuff related to bluetooth are already installed by simply searching for the word bluetooth.

Details:
Laptop Model: MSI CR41
OS Version: Ubuntu 13.04

So that is my big problem, how can I gain back my bluetooth? Because I badly needed this, this is what I used to transfer files from my phone to my laptop and vice versa. Looking forward for some help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install linux-firmware and linux-firmware-nonfree packages?
if not try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware && sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: Hello, I haven't installed that yet and I just did, but unfortunately, still I can't find any device nor my laptop got discovered by others. Thank you for your help, any other solution?

Comment: Take a look at this : [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186332/bluetooth-not-working-in12-04-dell-inspiron-15r), I hope it helps! ;)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but that was one of the posts I've read, followed and tried before posting my question here.